# Is it possible to accept and negate specific formats in a single regex?

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex to negatate 123-45-6789 and 123456789 (exact 9 digit numbers but it can be any combinations between 0-9) formats and allow everything else like alpha characters, any numbers except exact 9 digits, special characters but no leading and trailing spaces.

Here is my regex,

```
^(!~(\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4})&([0-9]{?!9}))|([a-zA-Z].\S)$
```

This matches most of my conditions except alphanumeric combinations, lesser/greater 9 digit numbers.

[image]

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Why is `Test123456789` a positive match?  Since it contains exactly 9 numbers, shouldn't it be failing?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, only exact 9 digits should not match, combination of anything with 9 digits should match.

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but much easier done in your programming language of choice instead of its regex implementation.

Comment: I agree, but I am working on .net MVC and need to add this regex as an attribute. I cannot add more than one RegexExpression attribute in .net MVC model, the only smartest way is to write a custom attribute, but it has some drawback as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
^(?!\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}$|\s|.*\s$).*$
```

See demo on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fW1oX6/1).

This uses `\s` for excluding text that starts or ends with white-space. If you really want to only exclude spaces there, but would accept tabs, non-breaking spaces, newlines, ... then replace `\s` with a plain space .

#### Accepting one hyphen

The above does not accept 9 digits when there are 0, 1 or 2 hyphens at the specific positions. If the case with 1 hyphen must be accepted, then do this:

```
^(?!\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$|\d{9}$|\s|.*\s$).*$
```

Comment: Above regex is not accepting this format 378-123333.

Comment: So you want to reject 9 digits only when there are either no hyphens or when there are 2 hyphens, but not when one? I added an alternative for that to my answer just now.

Comment: That's correct. Allow any formats other than the following numeric formats XXX-XXX-XXXX or XXXXXXXXX. Updated regex allows XXX-XXXXXX but not allowing above 9 digits. For Eg., 2344564347